# Issue reading text file with pound sign

Tags: python, numpy, csv, genfromtxt

I was trying to read a tab-delimited text file like this:

```
1 2# 3
```

using:

```
test = genfromtxt('test2.txt', delimiter='\t', dtype = 'string', skip_header=0)
```

However, I get the output only of 1 and 2. The # acts like an ending character in the txt file. Is there any way to solve this if I want to read the pound sign as a string?

Comment: try setting the `comments` parameter to some character that's not used.  see the `genfromtxt` documentation (that's where i looked)

Comment: ahaa. i see, this should explain and thx!!!!

Comment: Thank you jDigital. In addition, if you are not sure which characters will not be used, you can set `comments=None`

Answer (score 1):

`the_string.split('\t')` should do the job if you don't have to use `genfromtxt`

Comment: I have a large data set in the txt file. Here I just use a simple example. I think I have to use getfromtxt here.